# Typescript Sublime Plugin

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

Does Microsoft's Typescript Sublime Plugin (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin) include a linter? When I select View > Syntax > Typescript, a linter tells me that `require` is not defined:

[image]

Is this linter from Microsoft's plugin? I removed all other possibly responsible Sublime packages, but there is nothing in the documentation about the linter. And how do I get it to stop complaining about the `require`?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.

You need to use an import statement in TypeScript:

```
import a = require('phantom');
```

Also, make sure to have phantom's type declaration file—[`phantom.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/phantom/index.d.ts)—in your project.

Comment: When I use that syntax, it tries to locate the module even when I'm just cross-compiling the typescript to javascript and not actually running the javascript.

Comment: @TahsisClaus you need to tell typescript about that module by providing it the `phantom.d.ts` file in your project. The common way is to put it in a typings folder like `typings/phantom/phantom.d.ts` (this is what [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) does if you run `tsd install phantom` in the root directory of your project)

Comment: Do I have to provide the compiler the file route somehow? I used `tsd install phantom` and the compiler still throws an error abotu not being able to find it.

Comment: @TahsisClaus I feel like it should work if you can see the file already in sublime. I'm not as familiar with the sublime plugin though. You might have to add `/// <reference path="replace/with/relative/path/to/phantom.d.ts" />` to the top of your file or reference it in a [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file.

Comment: I got it to work after changing an option for gulp-typescript, though it can't find module 'webpage' (a phantomjs module), so I'm not actually sure it sees the phantom.d.ts file.

Answer (score 1):

> include a linter

Depends upon your definition of `linter`. TypeScript as a whole can be considered a powerful JavaScript linter + TypeScript transpiler ([more](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html))

> Is this linter from Microsoft's plugin

Yes.

## Quick fix

Because you don't have `require` function defined. You should include `node.d.ts` in your project.

## Better fix

And even better include `phantom.d.ts` and use `import/require`.

Comment: Where do I put .d.ts files?

Comment: anywhere that they would get picked up by `tsconfig.json`